# When the shallow network has a small number of neurons, how it will need more sum-product?

Tags: neural-networks

I am reading a paper, where I am not able to understand the meaning of the following statement, can someone please help.

```
a shallow network requires exponentially many more sum-product hidden units
than a deep sum-product network in order to compute certain families of polynomials.
```

[On the Number of Linear Regions of
Deep Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.1869.pdf)

Paticuality my question is, when the shallow network has a small number of neurons, how it will need more sum-product?

Comment: Small number of layers, not small number of neurons. (Perhaps that’s the misconception here?)

Comment: So does that mean if I increase the number of neurons in layers, it may work as if I am adding one more layer?

Comment: Except that you would need *exponentially more* neurons in the first strategy compared to the second.